# please help get data from json in swift

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, parsing, swiftui

I parsed data from a json file, but I don't know how to get these variables.
**Need charcode, name and value**.
[image]
I need to display them in a table using swiftui. I got a mess in the console and I don't know how to get to this data
[image]

this is struct

```
import Foundation

struct CurrencyModel: Codable {
    let valute: [String : Valute]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case valute = "Valute"
    }
}

struct Valute: Codable {
    let charCode, name: String
    let value: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case charCode = "CharCode"
        case name = "Name"
        case value = "Value"
    }
}
```

and this is parser

```
class FetchDataVM: ObservableObject {
    var valueData = [String : Any]()

    init() {
        fetchCurrency()
    }

    func fetchCurrency() {
        let urlString = "https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
    
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {data, _, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(CurrencyModel.self, from: data)
                        print(decodedData)
                  
                    } catch {
                        print("Error! Something went wrong.")
                    }
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all needed information is in the `Valute` struct you need only the values of the `valute` dictionary. Replace

```
var valueData = [String : Any]()
```

with

```
@Published var valueData = [Valute]()
```

and after the line `print(decodedData)` insert

```
self.valueData = decodedData.valute.values.sorted{$0.name < $1.name}
```

or

```
self.valueData = decodedData.valute.values.sorted{$0.charCode < $1.charCode}
```

In the view you can iterate the array simply with a `ForEach` expression

Comment: Also use the property wrapper @Published for `valueData` to update the view once the property is set

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I will test. You are best